# How to give delay value that is less than jiffies in delayed workqueue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

`queue_delayed_work(struct workqueue_struct *wq,struct delayed_work *dwork,unsigned long delay)`

In the above function, is it possible to give delay that is less than one jiffy?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a delay of zero or more jiffies. To get delay, kernel internally uses a timer. The earliest timer can expire is on the closest next tick. therefore the smallest delay possible is of 1 jiffies.  In case of zero jiffies, the delayed work (dwork) will immediately start without any delay.

[queue_delayed_work](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/workqueue.h#L500) internally calls [__queue_delayed_work](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/workqueue.c#L1504) where implementation for configuring timer is done. The minimum expire time is jiffies + delay. Refer links for more information.

To schedule your work less than jiffiy timer, You can make use of [hrtimers](https://elinux.org/High_Resolution_Timers)(high resolution timer).

For more information related to implementing hrtimer read followinf links :

[hrtimer repeating task in the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214197/hrtimer-repeating-task-in-the-linux-kernel)

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-timers-list/

Answer (score 0):

The only delay which would be less than one jiffy is 0 jiffies in case of `queue_delayed_work`.

`delay` has type `unsigned long` and it's specified as "number of jiffies to wait before queueing".

Comment: currently my jiffiy timer is 10ms i want to schedule my work less than jiffiy timer, Is there any other way to do this(Don't want to change the jiffy timer)

Comment: yes there is a way for scheduling your work for less than jiffy timer...It is by using the HRTimers ( High resolution timers). They give resolutions in terms of nanoseconds.

Comment: Go through links mentioned for implementing hrtimer.

Answer (score 0):

when we call wait_event_interruptible ( wq,
    condition)  is it mandatory to call wake_up function when we use  wait_event_interruptible ?